# How do I add settings to my DNN Module

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

How do I add a settings tab to my DNN Module??

I've added my User Control as a module to DNN but I don't know how to add a settings tab so that certain values become configurable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully you are using my Visual Studio Templates, they make doing DNN Module development, including Settings, super simple

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/bdd506ef-d5c3-4274-bf1d-9e673fb23484

Settings are easy without using my templates though, here's an ASCX for a setting

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="dnnFormItem">
        <dnn:label ID="lblPageSize" runat="server" ControlName="txtPageSize" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtPageSize" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div class="dnnFormItem">
        <dnn:label ID="lblShowCategories" runat="server" ControlName="chkShowCategories">
        </dnn:label>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkShowCategories" runat="server" />
    </div>
</fieldset>
```

Then the code behind

```
public override void LoadSettings()
{
    try
    {
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            //Check for existing settings and use those on this page
            //Settings["SettingName"]
            txtPageSize.Text = PageSize.ToString();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception exc) //Module failed to load
    {
        Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(this, exc);
    }
}

public override void UpdateSettings()
{
    try
    {
        PageSize = Convert.ToInt32(txtPageSize.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception exc) //Module failed to load
    {
        Exceptions.ProcessModuleLoadException(this, exc);
    }
}
```

Examples pulled from one of my open source modules

http://dnnsimplearticle.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#cs/

Answer (score 0):

To have DNN wire up your usercontrol to the settings tab under module settings, you need to add a new moduleControl definition into your .dnn manifest file. Below is the example from Chris' simplearticle sample module.

```
<moduleControl>
    <controlKey>Settings</controlKey>
    <controlSrc>DesktopModules/dnnsimplearticle/Settings.ascx</controlSrc>
    <supportsPartialRendering>False</supportsPartialRendering>
    <controlTitle>dnnsimplearticle Settings</controlTitle>
    <controlType>Edit</controlType>
    <iconFile />
    <helpUrl />
    <viewOrder>0</viewOrder>
</moduleControl>
```